# Issues reading from Windows Registry

Tags: c++, registry

I am attempting to read values from the Windows Registry.  I am reading one value from **HKLM\System** and one value from **HKLM\Software**.  I can easily read the value from System... but I cannot read the value from Software.

***Snippit from Registry Editor:***

[image]

***Snippit from ReadReg():***

```cpp
int ReadReg(LPCTSTR subkey, LPCTSTR name, DWORD type)
{
  HKEY key;
  TCHAR value[255];
  DWORD valuelen = 255;

  LONG result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkey, 0, KEY_READ, &key);
  cout << "RegOpenKeyEx Req is: " << subkey << endl;
  cout << "RegOpenKeyEx result is: " << PrintErrorCode(result) << endl;

  result = RegQueryValueEx(key, name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &valuelen);
  cout << "RegQueryValueEx Req is: " << name << endl;
  cout << "RegQueryValueEx result is: " << PrintErrorCode(result) << "\n" << endl;
  RegCloseKey(key);

  return 0;  
}
```

***Snippit from Inject():***

```cpp
int Inject()
{
  ReadReg("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Svchost", "demo", REG_MULTI_SZ);
  ReadReg("System\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\SvcHostDemo\\Parameters", "ServiceDll", REG_EXPAND_SZ);

  return 0;
}
```

***Snippit from Standard Out:***

[image]

The big question is... why can't I look at the value from "demo"?

Comment: Make sure you are not running under WOW64 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this.  I was able to add that to my code and IsWow64Process returned FALSE.  So I'm a 32-bit process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks a ton, both for pointing me in the right direction and for bringing up a good point about copying/pasting code instead of using screenshots!

KEY_WOW64_64KEY was the solution!  But... since I'm using g++, I also had to add a #define KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0X0100  :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Could you submit your comment as an answer so that I may highlight it as an answer?

Comment: @Stryker2k2 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag when calling `RegOpenKeyEx()`.  And you *should* change `KEY_READ` to `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` since you are just reading a value and don't need the other rights that `KEY_READ` grants.

Also, the last parameter of `RegQueryValueEx()` needs to be expressed in bytes, not in `TCHAR`s.

```cpp
#ifndef KEY_WOW64_64KEY
#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0x0100
#endif

int ReadReg(LPCTSTR subkey, LPCTSTR name, DWORD type)
{
  HKEY key;
  TCHAR value[255];
  DWORD valuelen = sizeof(value);

  LONG result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &key);
  cout << "RegOpenKeyEx Req is: " << subkey << endl;
  cout << "RegOpenKeyEx result is: " << PrintErrorCode(result) << endl;

  result = RegQueryValueEx(key, name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &valuelen);
  cout << "RegQueryValueEx Req is: " << name << endl;
  cout << "RegQueryValueEx result is: " << PrintErrorCode(result) << "\n" << endl;
  RegCloseKey(key);

  return 0;  
}
```